# Resume all upload tasks when network re-connect in AFNetworking

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking, nsurlsession, reachability

I´m using `AFNetworking 3.0`. I have successfully uploaded tasks using background session. Now I want to suspend and resume all tasks based on network reachablity. Like suspend tasks when no-network and resume task when network reconnect.

**Code:**

```
static AFURLSessionManager *manager;

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"wts.Demo-Upload"];
    sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 20;
    manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
});

[manager setDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSessionBlock:^(NSURLSession * _Nonnull session) {
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler) {
        void (^completionHandler)() = appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler;
        appDelegate.backgroundSessionCompletionHandler = nil;
        completionHandler();
    }

    NSLog(@"All tasks are finished");
}];



NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = manager.operationQueue;

[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            // we need to notify a delegete when internet conexion is lost.
            // [delegate internetConexionLost];
            NSLog(@"No Internet Conexion");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"WIFI");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"3G");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unkown network status");
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
    }
}];
    [manager.reachabilityManager startMonitoring];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found solution. 
First get all upload tasks and resume it.

```
[manager.reachabilityManager setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {

    switch (status) {
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusNotReachable:
            NSLog(@"No Internet Connection");
            break;
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWiFi:
            NSLog(@"WiFi");
        case AFNetworkReachabilityStatusReachableViaWWAN:
            NSLog(@"3G");
            for (NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask in [manager uploadTasks]) {
                [uploadTask resume];
            }
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown network status");
            [operationQueue setSuspended:YES];
            break;
    }
}];
```

Above code works fine when app is on foreground. But `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock` is never called when app is in the background.
Can anyone know how to call reachability block even app is in background?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22197630/ios-reachability-notification-in-background/44236311#44236311